# Does Files.isExecutable make sense for directories on Windows?

Tags: java, windows

The [Files.isExecutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isExecutable-java.nio.file.Path-) Java method tests whether a path (file or directory) is executable.

The documentation mentions the special case of directories:

> The semantics may differ when checking access to a directory. For example, on UNIX systems, checking for execute access checks that the Java virtual machine has permission to search the directory in order to access file or subdirectories.

What, specifically, happens on Windows? Does an "executable" directory make any sense there?